# How to customize NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, textview, view, customization

I have the seguent NavigationDrawer and it is ok:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

The problem is born when I try to customize my `navigationDrawer`, It should insert a `"static"` Text in my `ListView` (like a `TextView`) not like in `adapter`.

Comment: you can use custom listview there.

Comment: i want a textView and other components of listView like in adapter...

Comment: this is listview where you can inflate custom listview with adapter.

Comment: you can check on this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: refer these for more better navigation drawer implementation : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ , http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/